# Sticky footer - trying to understand the code

Tags: html, css

I wanted to implement a sticky footer that will be pushed to bottom if content is less.

I have gone through various posts in this website and could see that two popular solutions *(without flexbox)* uses either

```
html, body 
{    
    height: 100%; 
}
```

OR

```
html 
{     
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%; 
}
```

I am posting only the parts of the solution which I did not understand. Posting my doubts here. Please help me to understand these solutions

(a) as stated, first solution uses 100% height for html and body. But what is 100% height here? Is it refers to the height of view port or height of the entire document?

(b) in first solution, If 100% height refers only to view port height, isn't it required to make the setting to min-height instead of height because if document is larger than the view port, restricting to 100% height is not relevant.

(c) I know we make a element relative so that its child absolute/relative elements gets position from it. But what is the meaning of making html relative as it has only document as its parent?

(d) also, from your experience is there any better solution (without flexbox)? Similarly there are many posts with respect to issues in mobile browsers while using such solutions (like ios8 issue when using 100vh). Whether these solutions have any such issues?

My html knowledge is very much limited. thanks for help.

*Note: both solutions are working fine and giving sticky footer as required*

Comment: How come you dont want to use flexbox? It's far superior if you are really wanting a fixed footer/header

Comment: I am not using flexbox only because of ie10 https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Who is still using ie10? 
Looks like it's a pretty [small market share](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0)

Comment: @KevinJantzer, u mentioned flexbox is superior, how? the css solutions mentioned are also working. or are there any issues with the solutions i mentioned in some browsers/mobile browsers?

Comment: flexbox is easier and more reliable once you start adding multiple fixed elements such as a footer, header and sidebar, but you can make it work with floats and position too.

Comment: I agree. Flexbox is amazing and apart of the css spec. I wouldn't worry about ie10. Even WordPress ended support for ie10: https://wptavern.com/wordpress-4-8-will-end-support-for-internet-explorer-versions-8-9-and-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A)

The `html` and `body` tags do not fill the entire window by default, so that code forces to be 100% of screen even when inside content is less.

Without:[image]

With 100%:[image]

### B)

[You can get away](https://jsfiddle.net/7quhq3kb/) with having the `<body>` as 100% because the content inside by default will overflow and the `<html>` tag has `overflow:auto` on by default.

So, the following works, but the content will overflow the `<body>`

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

A [better solution](https://jsfiddle.net/7quhq3kb/1/) would be one of the following:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[Or](https://jsfiddle.net/7quhq3kb/2/)

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i see. But, if the content is more than the view port, then isn't setting 100% on html a mistake?

Comment: I mean, then min-height must be a better solution than height, am i correct?